# When changing the page size, the element moves

Tags: html, css

Why when I resize the page, the circles remain the same, but the check mark inside goes down. How to fix it and keep it relative?

```css
.circle{
    background-color: green;
    height: 3.7vh;
    width: 3.7vh;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-left: 1.25vw;
    background-color: #bbb;
    border-radius: 50vw;
    display: inline-block;
}

img{
   display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    line-height: normal;
    width: 0.83vw;
    height: 1.48vh;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<span class="circle">
    <img src="gal.svg"/>
</span>
<span class="circle">
</span>
```

[image]

url to img : https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDpc1.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is another way to solve your problem with the help of Flexbox.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Solution</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .circle {
                background-color: green;
                height: 3.7vh;
                width: 3.7vh;
                margin-left: 1.25vw;
                border-radius: 50vw;
                display: flex;
                justify-content: center;
                align-items: center;
            }

            img {
                width: 0.5rem;
                height: 0.5rem;                  
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="circle">
            <img
                src="your_image_path"
            />
        </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I feel very happy to help you.
Thanks, have a nice day.

Comment: Lot of unnecessary css rules for the image. When parent is `flex` and centers horizontally and vertically, the only thing you need is `width` and `height` on the image.

Answer (score 0):

First way to solve your problem with the help of position property of css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Solution</title>
        <style>
            * {
                margin: 0;
                padding: 0;
                box-sizing: border-box;
            }
            .circle {
                background-color: green;
                height: 3.7vh;
                width: 3.7vh;
                vertical-align: top;
                margin-left: 1.25vw;
                border-radius: 50vw;
                display: inline-block;
                position: relative;
            }

            img {
                display: inline-block;
                position: absolute;
                top: 30%;
                left: 30%;
                width: 0.5rem;
                height: 0.5rem;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <span class="circle">
            <img
                src="your_images_path"
            />
        </span>

        <span class="circle"> </span>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/Nt7Qd4n.png